# how to check for empty "//" slashes in a input field

Tags: javascript

I want to check whether a regex field is empty or not and depending on that I want to execute a function.
the input field is a regex field and by default it stores "//" value in the field and I dont want to execute a function if the value contains "//" . Only when user enters some value I would wnat to execute the function.

```
new shared.form.RegexField({
                            ref : 'regexField',
                            fieldLabel : 'Regular Expression',
                            allowBlank : false,
                            width : 300,
});
```

Ex:

```
var rule = "//";
if(rule) {
// dont do anything;
}
```

however if rule contains some value like:

```
rule = "/test/";
if(rule) {
// call API sevrice.
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: Why not `if (rule !== '//') { ... }` or `if (rule.length > 2) { ... } `? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the problem here. If you can get the string version of your regex, why not just check if `rule === '//'` to not execute the function?

Comment: Could also be something like `/[a-z]+/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rule = '//www.example.com'
if(rule.replace(/(\/\/)(?=(\S)*)/,'')){
  //  call API sevrice.
}else {
 // dont do anything;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (rule.match("/\/\//")) {
    // don't call because it's equal to "//"
} else {
    // call API service
}
```